# Use custom get results query to show posts WordPress

Tags: php, wp-query, customization

I have this code before to show posts.

```
$query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'meta_key' => 'Views',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if( $the_query->have_posts() )
{
    while( $the_query->have_posts() )
    {
        $the_query->the_post();                 
        echo    '<a class="popularPostLinks" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="external" target="_blank">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>
                        </div>
                </a>';
    }
}
else
{
    // No posts found.
}
// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

but now i am using my custom query:

```
$getAllTimeRows = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id, SUM( post_value ) AS 'Views' FROM {$wpdb->prefix}PopularPosts GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY Views DESC LIMIT 4" ) );
```

How can i used this above array result to show posts same like how WP Query is showing the posts? The `$getAllTimeRows` contains rows (max 4) to show (max 4) posts. See below the array.

```
print_r ( $getAllTimeRows  )

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 213
            [Views] => 16
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 215
            [Views] => 11
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 217
            [Views] => 9
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 227
            [Views] => 7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get same result by outputting values from PHP array. Since it is multicolumn array, you will need to run `foreach` loop and get values of each child item.

Mostly it's standard PHP stuff, nothing special. Although earlier you did not need to supply post ID in each WordPress function since you were using it inside a loop, but now you will have to do that.

So here is the output.

```
foreach( $getAllTimeRows as $getAllTimeRow ) {

    $post_id_num = $getAllTimeRow->post_id;

    echo '<a class="popularPostLinks" href="' . get_permalink( $post_id_num ) . '" rel="external" target="_blank">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id_num ) . '<br>
        <div>
            <p>' . get_the_title( $post_id_num ) . '</p>
        </div>
    </a>';

}
```

Comment: thanks alot. i am new to wordpress and this is really helpful to me. again thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem. :) I am glad I could help you with this.